# Exclude time comparison from Datetime field in Dynamic LINQ Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, expression

I want to generate a dynamic LINQ expression for filtering only with Date, but my column is a Datetime field in the DB. Due to this the operator "equal" and "not equal" is not working because it is appending some default time to my input and trying to match with the data. If there is any way to Generate a LINQ expression that will compare only date by excluding the time.

This is my code:

```
// for type conversion start
var propertyType = ((PropertyInfo)propertyName.Member).PropertyType;
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(propertyType);

if (!converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
     throw new NotSupportedException();

var propertyValue = ReturnPropertyValue(rule, converter);
var constant = Expression.Constant(propertyValue);
var valueExpression = Expression.Convert(constant, propertyType); //{Convert(5/24/2021 12:00:00 AM, DateTime)}
// for type conversion ends

// returning the expression
return Expression.Equal(propertyName, valueExpression);     
// {(Param_0.CreatedDate == Convert(5/24/2021 12:00:00 AM, DateTime))}
```

But here I need something like this

```
{(Param_0.CreatedDate == Convert(5/24/2021 12:00:00 AM, Date))}
```

Which will exclude this time checking and will compare only with date

Comment: I realize this isn't the exact question so I won't put it as an answer, but a pretty common workaround for this would be to expand your comparison to include two conditions, one for greater than or equal to the start of the date (00:00:00) and less than the next day start (00:00:00) - in case you hadn't thought of that approach.

Comment: @LawrenceJohnson : the above solution will work but just I want something like in the expression itself adding some condition/constant(like StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) to avoid time checking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do it; go the route suggested of using a date range instead

Always seek to avoid creating queries that manipulate table data before a comparison is done. Suppose you have a table with ten million datetimes in, and they're all indexed

The database will probably use the index for this:

```
WHERE datecol >= '2001-01-01' and datecol < '2001-01-02'
```

The database will probably not use the index for this:

```
WHERE CAST(datecol as DATE) = '2001-01-01'
```

.. so *every time you query* the db will fully scan either the table or the index, converting every one of all ten million values before doing the comparison

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below code in C# linq:-

```
var data = collection.Where(t=> DbFunctions.TruncateTime(t.CreatedDate)==DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dateVariable)).ToList();
```

above code will exclude the time while doing field comparison in Linq.

Comment: My question is about how to do the same in Dynamic Linq Expression not in direct LINQ